# Flink function extended ListCheckpointed doesn't restore from checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink

I'd like to use ListCheckpointed to store map in my windowfunciton(map is shared by keys, so I used operator state), but map isn't restored from checkpoint after restarting.

At first, I used Map stored in memory to trigger map calculation when later key arrives in window function. When job is restarted, Map is lost so I consider to store map in operator state. 
I've set checkpoint in environment, snapshotState function was dispatched, but map wasn't restored from checkpoint when I canceled job and start it again.

job code:

```
    var config:Configuration = new Configuration()
    config.setBoolean(ConfigConstants.LOCAL_START_WEBSERVER, true)
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(config)
    env.setParallelism(parallelism.toInt)
    env.enableCheckpointing(10 * 1000L)
    env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend(checkpointProps("directory")))
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(500)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)

    val stream = env
    ...//do watermarks
    .keyBy(a => a.room + "_" + a.role)
 .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(20 * 1000)))
      .apply(new myWindowFunciton())
    env.execute(name)
```

myWindowFunciton code:

```
class myWindowFunciton extends RichWindowFunction[myForm, myForm, String, TimeWindow]
        with ConfigParse with Serializable with Logging  with ListCheckpointed[util.HashMap[String, (myForm, myForm)]] {
    var map2: util.HashMap[String, (myForm, myForm)] = new util.HashMap[String, (myForm, myForm)]()
    ...
    override def apply...
    ...
    override def snapshotState(checkpointId: Long, timestamp: Long): util.List[util.HashMap[String, (myForm, myForm)]] = {
        println("snap map is " + map2.size().toString())
        util.Collections.singletonList(map2)
    }

    override def restoreState(stateList: util.List[util.HashMap[String, (myForm, myForm)]]): Unit = {
        println("restoreState size is " + stateList.size().toString)
        for(stateMap <- stateList.asScala) {
            println("restore every time is " + stateMap.size().toString())
            map2.putAll(stateMap)
        }

        println("after restore:" + map2.size().toString())
    }

}
```

I tested in Intellij Idea. I Started and println in snapshotState printed messages, but println in restoreState never was executed when program was canceled in webui and restarted.

Comment: If you're manually cancelling a Flink job, then there's no auto-restore from checkpoint. To really test checkpointing, you'll want to cause the job to fail, and then it should auto-restart from the last checkpoint.

Comment: You're right, thanks.  I should use savepoint if I wanna explicitly trigger my job from cancellation.